# Hybris: difference between promotion and voucher

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

I am working on POC on promotions and vouchers. I was going through hybris documentations at most all kind of discounts are covered in promotion Engine.

I also noticed we have coupon promotion too. Having said this, in which case we will chose over vouchers?

It would be great if you can explain me with a example.

Promotion: https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/6badeeed32a546689404b9897f8d54ee.html

Voucher:
https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c7fc4e886691014b2ace5fe565624a1.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Broadly speaking,

***Promotions*** are **implicit**. The customer has no control over it. If the order qualifies for a promotion then it would definitely be applied.

***Vouchers*** are **explicitly** applied. The customer is given a voucher number. If and only if the customer enters the voucher number during the checkout process, the voucher will be applied.

Comment: yes makes sense but we have coupon promotions for which customer has control. Please add some light to it

Comment: @user3501569 : Coupon promotions in Hybris are stored as `PromotionVoucherModel`. Promotion vouchers are purely vouchers NOT promotions. The `PromotionVoucherModel` extends `VoucherModel`. These are special types of vouchers having a single serial number that can be used by different customers again and again.
The name is a little misleading, though.